# How to run compass compile without file or line reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, compass

How can I suppress file or line reference such as the commented output line below when running `compass compile` and possibly keep `--output-style` expanded by default?

```
/* line 85, ../../../app/stylesheets/simpla/style.sass */
.align-right { 
  float: right;
}
```

The problem is whenever I make 1 line change in sass, it makes 50+ line changes to my css to update all the reference line numbers that got adjusted. This makes it really hard to read the actual changes in my git commit.

Answer (score 11):

Nevermind, just figured it out. In config/compass.rb, set:

```
line_comments = false
```

This will suppress/remove the comments from the compiled css files.

Comment: BTW, where does the `config/compass.rb` file lies ? I am almost in same situation and need to edit the compass config. I am using `rvm` and `compass 0.12`

Comment: I was using rails with compass, so it was under my project directory/config/compass.rb

Comment: What to do if I'm not using Compass only Sass?

Answer (score 0):

Just to update previous answer, by Chase T.

For me this is not working anymore.

```
line_comments = false
```

should become

```
line_comments = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From command-line, try:

```
compass compile --no-line-comments
```

---

If you're using Grunt and [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass), it's `noLineComments: true`, e.g.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            src: {
                files: ['**/*.scss', '**/*.php'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'sass',
                    cssDir: 'css',
                    imagesPath: 'img',
                    noLineComments: true,
                    outputStyle: 'compressed'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

then run: `grunt compass`.