# precompile assets - rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm setting up first ruby site in production, everything works ok, but when I run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It adds the css/js in "public/assets/" directory ok, but they have paths and line numbers in the files? So was just wondering how to get it all on one line and without line numbers/comments? Have I missed a setting or anything for this? Here is an example of how my `application-428d86248ca363.css` comes out:

```
/* line 1, /home/joe/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss */
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

/* line 6, /home/joe/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss */
#head {
  background: #666;
}
/* line 4, /home/joe/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss */
.block {
  color: #1e1e1e;
}
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 */
```

Also you can see it includes the big comment at end. How do  I get it to go all on one line with no comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCSS**

> they have paths and line numbers in the files

That's a problem with SCSS which *should* resolve if you use `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

---

**Fix**

Whilst looking for a reference, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080662/compass-compile-without-file-or-line-reference) and [this github](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/157):

```
Just to update previous answer, by Chase T.

For me this is not working anymore.

     #config/compass.rb
     line_comments = false

should become

     line_comments = 0
```

Considering the resource uses `compass.rb`, I looked to see how to do it in a standard Rails app. I found the way to do it is to use a system, and looks like you can use this command:

```
#config/application.rb
config.sass.line_comments = false
```

This is confirmed with [this information](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3513):

> Using Rails 4.1 and after looking and looking (and possibly misreading
>   the documentation) I got this to work by adding the following to
>   `/config/environments/development.rd & production.rb`
>
> `config.sass.preferred_syntax = :scss`
>
> `config.sass.style = :compact`
>
> `config.sass.line_comments = false`
>
> Style can be set to :nested,
>   :expanded, :compact, :compressed. You can see the different options
>   here:
>   http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
>
> Also, make sure to restart your server to see the compiled version
>   change
>
> Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rich, that did the job!

Comment: using "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" did the job nicely. Didn't have to add anything to application file.