# How to specify line_comments in compass compile?

Tags: css, eclipse, compilation, sass, compass

I am using Eclipse IDE and I use compass to compile my .scss file. For this I have created a builder which I manually trigger whenever required. But each time I run this builder it adds lots of comments in generated .css file.  I see we can use `line_comments=false` and that should fix my problem. 
[How to run compass compile without file or line reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080662/compass-compile-without-file-or-line-reference)

But the point is where should I specify this. I don't have any compass.rb file. Can I somehow specify this in command line. As of now I am using this:

```
compile --css-dir=./css
```

Comment: Sorry to say, I overlooked this param `--no-line-comments` :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `--no-line-comments` in command line argument to disable generating line comments.
**Example**:

```
compile --css-dir=./css --no-line-comments
```